# Why is $\sum_{i=1}^6 2^i = 2^7-2$?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics, summation

> Why is $$\sum_{i=1}^6 2^i = 2^7-2$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here.

Answer (score 7):

$$\sum_{i=1}^6 2^i =2+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6$$ $$= 2(1+2+2^2+..+2^5) = 2{2^6-1\over 2-1} =2^7-2$$

We have generaly $$1+x+x^2+...+x^n = {x^{n+1}-1\over x-1}$$

Comment: So, in fact, this is true for sums up to $n$

Answer (score 3):

We use Geometric series (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). That is, we have
$$ \sum_{i=0}^k n^i = \frac{n^{k+1} - 1}{n - 1}.$$
So rewriting your series, we have
$$ \sum_{i=1}^6 2^i = 2 \sum_{i=0}^5 2^i = 2 \left(\frac{2^6 - 1}{2 -1} \right) = 2^7 - 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

In context, binary arithmetic:

$\sum_{i=1}^{6}2^i= 1111110.$

$\sum_{i=1}^{6}2^i +2=$

$1111110+10=$

$10000000 =2^7.$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see it is to note that the series is telescoping. Indeed,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^6 2 ^i&=\sum_{i=1}^6 (2 ^{i+1}-2^i)\\&=(2^2-2^1)+(2^3-2^2)+
(2^4-2^3)+
(2^5-2^4)+
(2^6-2^5)+
(2^7-2^6)\\
&=2^7-2.
\end{align}
$$